# Issues while running powershell script using windows service (Error Code = 5)

Tags: c#, windows, powershell, windows-services

I've created a Windows service in C# and added a powershell script to execute OnStart(). Tried running the script and it threw "Error Level 5 : Access is Denied". How can I run the powershell script using Admin privileges which would help me bypass the issue.

```
protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
    {
        while(!Debugger.IsAttached)
        {
            System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000);
        }
        WriteToFile("Service is started at " + DateTime.Now);

        int errorLevel;
        try
        {
            string ps = @"C:/Projects/E/CreateSiteCollection.ps1";
            ProcessStartInfo processInfo;
            Process process;

            processInfo = new ProcessStartInfo("powershell_ise.exe", ps);
            process = Process.Start(processInfo);
            process.WaitForExit();

            errorLevel = process.ExitCode;
            process.Close();
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            WriteToFile(ex.InnerException.ToString());
        }

        WriteToFile("Service Completed at " + DateTime.Now);

    }
```

Comment: Under which user account your service is configured to run?

Comment: @montonero Right now I haven't configured any account to run the service. So I believe it runs with my user account. My concern is how will I be able to run the powershell using administrator access. Not sure if this answers your questions.

Comment: It would be nice if you look what exact user is configured for the service and show it to us.

Comment: @montonero Can you help me on how can I check that ?

Comment: Open `Services` snap-in in `Administrative Tools` (or just type `services` in Windows search), find your service there, open its properties and go to `Log On` tab

Comment: Checked the Log On table and it says 
Log on as : "Local System Account"

Comment: Local System account have enough privileges to run almost anything. It would be nice to see a screenshot of the error you have.

Comment: I'm receiving the process.ExitCode as 5, which reflects to "Access is Denied" https://i.imgur.com/EtDdZIx.png

Comment: Why you use forward slashes in the path?

Comment: Forward slashes don't matter I believe. Pardon me if that's a vague way of doing it.

Comment: @montonero I believe I found the catch. It was because I was running it under ISE and not JUST powershell. Thanks for your time. Happy coding.

Comment: That' was a next question I've planned to ask :)